# Node.js - File upload with progress

Tags: node.js, curl, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file through curl --upload-file  
For some reason, curl freezes and upload.backup get created empty. Any ideas how this code should be changed to make it work? I must be misunderstanding the APIs

```
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var fileBackup = fs.createWriteStream("upload.backup");
    var fileBytes = request.headers['content-length'];
    var uploadedBytes = 0;
    request.on('readable', function() {
        var chunk = null;
        while (null !== (chunk = request.read())) {
            uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
            var progress = uploadedBytes / fileBytes * 100;
            response.write("progress: " + parseInt(progress, 10) + "%\n");
        }
    });
    request.pipe(fileBackup);
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you're not ending your response. Secondly, you're reading the data from the request stream before it can be written to the file.

Try something like this instead:

```
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var fileBackup = fs.createWriteStream('upload.backup');
  var fileBytes = parseInt(request.headers['content-length'], 10);
  var uploadedBytes = 0;
  request.pipe(fileBackup);
  if (!isNaN(fileBytes)) {
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
      uploadedBytes += chunk.length;
      response.write('progress: ' + (uploadedBytes / fileBytes * 100) + '%\n');
    });
  }
  request.on('end', function() {
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```